# couple c++ and ees (engineering equation solver)

Tags: c++, coupling

I would like to know if it is possible to couple c++ and ees (engineering equation solver). In fact, i would like to calculate thermophysical properties of the water by calling a function from ees in c++ and what are the steps to follow. For now, i am calculating the properties in ees and inserting them in c++ via a .txt file, but it would be better if i call a function directly from ees. 
I am using the following code to read the file and assign the columns to a 2d vector.

```
ifstream myReadFile;
myReadFile.open("Tc.txt");

while (!myReadFile.eof()) {

    for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++){
            myReadFile  >> data[i][j];
            cout << "\n data [" << i<< j<< "] =" << data[i][j];
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

EES Professional Version actually has a command line interface, take a look at here:
http://www.fchart.com/ees/eeshelp/hs608.htm

With this, it is possible to generate an emf macro and execute it during runtime using the `system` C++ call:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/

It would look something like this:

```
generateEmfScript() // your code to generate the script to be run
system("path_to\\ees.exe  myscript.emf")
```

Then you can just read the result as before.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I actually want to call the function that calculates the thermophysical properties directly in c++ instead of reading the results only.

Comment: That's what it is about. You can save your function call as a script and run ees to calculate it, then read the result... Realtime.